# Does Bytescout.PDFExtractor supported in .net core 2.0/2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, export-to-csv

I want to extract a PDF and convert it into a CSV file. I'm using `Bytescout.PDFExtractor` for this purpose. It works with the .NET Framework, but when I try it with .NET Core 2.0/2.1, an exception arises at the last line while saving the CSV file:

```
 // Create Bytescout.PDFExtractor.CSVExtractor instance
 CSVExtractor extractor = new CSVExtractor();
 extractor.RegistrationName = "demo";
 extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo";

 // Load sample PDF document
 extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile(@"D:\File.pdf");

 extractor.SaveCSVToFile(@"D:\NewFile.csv");
```

This is the exception:

[image: System.Drawing is not supported]

Comment: Please add the exception to your question :-)

Comment: Sorry, failed to upload, added it now.

Comment: I tested the code , and it worked well . From [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bytescout.PDFExtractor/) , ByteScout is compatible with .NET Framework 2.0 or later and .NET Core 2.0 or later. Could you share a simple project that can reproduce the issue ?